# PHP MongoDB SUM all columns

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is there anyway in which MongoDB aggregate framework can be used to sum up all the columns or an array of columns rather than just one?

Each row has a 'category id'. I'm hoping to filter by a specific category id and then output a row which is the sum of each of the columns. As I wont be needing all of the columns, it would be better if I could specify columns to increase performance.

I have seen examples of this done with 1 column however not with multiple columns.

Below is example data

```
{ "type" : "A", "a" : 1,  "b" : 2,  "c" : 3, "d" : 4 }
{ "type" : "A", "a" : 10, "b" : 20, "c" : 30, "d" : 40 }
{ "type" : "B", "a" : 1,  "b" : 2,  "c" : 3, "d" : 4 }
{ "type" : "B", "a" : 10, "b" : 20, "c" : 30, "d" : 40 }
```

The result therefore when the type is B would be

```
{ "type" : "B", "a" : 11, "b" : 22, "c" : 33, "d" : 44 }
```

As can be seen, each of the columns have been summed up, and a single row is returned with the sum of each column.

I am using PHP and the latest version of MongoDB with Debian

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example your data and what you want as a result? And in JSON format please.

Comment: Sorry, my question was ambiguous ... I've updated with an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have your data for a clear example, but you seem to be basically looking for the [**`$add`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) operator which "add" a list of supplied values together. So given a sample of documents:

```
{ "type" : "A", "a" : 1,  "b" : 2,  "c" : 3, "d" : 4 }
{ "type" : "A", "a" : 10, "b" : 20, "c" : 30, "d" : 40 }
{ "type" : "B", "a" : 1,  "b" : 2,  "c" : 3, "d" : 4 }
{ "type" : "B", "a" : 10, "b" : 20, "c" : 30, "d" : 40 }
```

There is this example to "add" all the "columns" together for "a", "b" and "c" only. Also grouping by "type":

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$type",
        "total": { "$sum": { "$add": [ "$a", "$b", "$c" ] } }
    }}
])
```

You can also use [**`$add`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) with [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) if you do not need to [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) or are otherwise working with data at a different level.

The result on this data would be:

```
{ "_id" : "B", "total" : 66 }
{ "_id" : "A", "total" : 66 }
```

---

What you are actually asking though is just doing a [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) for each column:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$type",
        "a": { "$sum": "$a" },
        "b": { "$sum": "$b" },
        "c": { "$sum": "$c" },
        "d": { "$sum": "$d" }
    }}
])
```

Which produces:

```
{ "_id" : "B", "a" : 11, "b" : 22, "c" : 33, "d" : 44 }
{ "_id" : "A", "a" : 11, "b" : 22, "c" : 33, "d" : 44 }
```

Comment: sorry .. walked away --- but that looks exactly what I'm after ... I will test now and let you know.... thanks

Comment: Should also note that the above solution seems to return ok but with a blank result

Comment: @user1641165 Works for me. How are you quoting in PHP? note you need things like '$a' and not "$a" which will interpolate.

Comment: yes ... you are right .... your solution does work ... I made a mistake. I'm testing you're solution with the terminal first as it's not made for PHP. I'm getting only one total however and I would like 3 totals for each of the columns

Comment: @user1641165 This is why examples are important to your question. This is just simple `$sum` aggregation.

Comment: Wow .... that's brilliant ...and yes, I see your point :) ... thank you very much for your time and help.... will accept now